# Execute workflow if picklist value is NOT equal to "ABC"

Tags: workflow, formula, email-alert

if pick-list value of Lead Status is not equal to "ABC" i want to execute workflow rule. If it is equal to "ABC" it shouldn't run the rule. How do i achieve this in formula field.
I tried using ISPICKLIST VALUE, but couldn't figure it out.

appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) When you create the workflow rules select "Run this rule if the following" `criteria are met` instead of `formula evaluates to true`.

2) Select your field (picklist)

3) Select `not equal to` operator

4) Choose the value you're comparing against ("ABC") in your case

> EDIT:
>
> If you're using this in combination with other logic and you must use
>   formula, the following formula should work:
>
> `NOT(ISPICKVAL('Status', 'ABC'))`

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't use that option. I have few other criteria that i'm including this with. Should have mentioned in the text :). Thanks for the response.

Comment: Can you use the filter logic or you must use formula? I've edited the answer for the formula.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! NOT(ISPICKVAL('Status', 'ABC')) is perfect.